# How do i set a request.referrer inside my RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to avoid using my `session[:referred_by]`, and would like to use the `request.referrer`.  However, my RSpec tests fail because the `TestRequest` does not store a `request.referrer`

So I have to do the following in order for Rspec tests to work. Is there a way to make it better:

```
referrer = request.referrer ? request.referrer : '/'
redirect_to referrer, :alert => error_message
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Mock it:

```
specify 'foo' do
  controller.request.should_receive(:referer).and_return('http://example.com')
  # get whatever
end
```

Or if you don't care if it doesn't get called, stub it:

```
controller.request.stub referer: 'http://example.com'
```

Comment: The answer by Simone Carletti is cleaner because it handles both spellings of `referer`/`referrer`

Answer (score 50):

`ActionDispatch::TestRequest` extends `ActionDispatch::Request` that extends `Rack::Request`.

The method is defined as follows

```
def referer
  @env['HTTP_REFERER']
end
alias referrer referer
```

As far as I remember, you can access the environment variable in the RSpec test by using `request.env`. It means, it should be possible to set something like

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://example.com'
```

Of course, it depends on the type of RSpec example group you are using.

Comment: `request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://example.com'` worked for me.
Rspec version is 3.4.4

Answer (score 16):

On Rails 5 the accepted solution doesn't seem to work anyore, but setting `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` directly, as [Simone Carletti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123527/simone-carletti) suggests, works.

Answer (score 10):

### Solution for Rails 5.2+ & RSpec 3.8+

```rb
get :endpoint, params: {}, headers: { 'HTTP_REFERER' => 'stackoverflow.com' }
```

Comment: If `headers` already exists (usually for authentication), we can merge them: `headers: headers.merge( { 'HTTP_REFERER' => 'stackoverflow.com' } )`

Comment: @Lucas Caton Didn't work for me. `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: headers`

Answer (score 2):

With Rails4/Rspec3, in request specs, `request` is not available until you make an http call. But you can assign request.referer by doing something like this:

```
get '/posts', {}, { referer: 'http://example.com' }
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works in controllers specs:

```
controller.request.headers.merge({ 'HTTP_REFERER': 'https://stackoverflow.com/' })
get(:endpoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else Googling this, you can also stub the request in a helper spec like this:

```
allow(view).to receive_message_chain(:request, :referrer).and_return("http://example.com")
```