# How to redirect_to request.referrer for Devise authenticated controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to get a test to pass. The controller action I'm testing finishes with `redirect_to request.referrer` and it works in development.

In my controller test however I'm getting:

> ActionController::ActionControllerError: Cannot redirect to nil!

Here's the test:

```
it 'should update a group' do
  put :update, id: group1.id, group: { name: 'foo' }
  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

I have other tests for the same controller that...

```
expect(response).to be_success
```

...and they pass, provided the action they test finishes by rendering or redirecting to something that is not `request.referer`.

I'm authenticating my user in that controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

I have each example preceded with:

```
before(:each) do
  sign_in user1
end
```

I'm configuring RSpec like so:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

From what I understand if I pass a headers hash to my test request (for example with 'HTTP_REFERER') it will overwrite the one from Devise. Is the solution here to properly set that hash?

I'm using **rspec-rails** (3.5.2), **devise** (4.2.0), **rails** (5.0.0.1)

Comment: Have you tried the following options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591763/how-do-i-set-a-request-referrer-inside-my-rspec

Comment: @tkz79 that got me sorted out. Thank you.